# Matching Hashed + Salted Passwords

Tags: python, encryption, hash, sha256, conceptual

I'm learning about encryption and security and I'm a little confused by a (possibly simple) concept.

I understand how hashing and salts work for the most part, but I don't understand how functions match passwords. For example, here is part of passlib's documentation:

```
>>> # import the hash algorithm
>>> from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

>>> # generate new salt, and hash a password
>>> hash = sha256_crypt.encrypt("toomanysecrets")
>>> hash
'$5$rounds=80000$zvpXD3gCkrt7tw.1$QqeTSolNHEfgryc5oMgiq1o8qCEAcmye3FoMSuvgToC'

>>> # verifying the password
>>> sha256_crypt.verify("toomanysecrets", hash)
True
>>> sha256_crypt.verify("joshua", hash)
False
```

On the 4th line, it mentions generating a new salt, but as far as I can tell the salt is never stored alongside the password.

**Why can I can store the hashed password as a string in a database and verify it later without providing a salt?**

Answer (score 3):

Per [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html#format-algorithm):

> An sha256-crypt hash string has the format `$5$rounds=rounds$salt$checksum`

The salt (in your case `'zvpXD3gCkrt7tw.1'`) is stored *within the string itself*; that's why it doesn't need to be stored separately.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I looked through the documentation, but must have missed that.